# Second Font dedicated for tables

Tags: tables, beamer, fonts, tabu

How to put second font in table. First is Utopia Regular with Math Design as a main font. Second - TeX Gyre Heros, for tables.

```
\documentclass{beamer}      
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign} %main font

\usepackage{tgheros} %second font - for tables
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabu}

\usecolortheme{crane}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Wynagrodzenia}
\begin{table}
\tabulinesep =_4pt^4pt
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth{@{}cX[m]X[c]X[c]X[c]@{}}
   \tabucline[1.0pt blue!40 off 0pt]{-}
   \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{procesy} & Min & Max  &\\
   \tabucline[0.7pt blue!40 off 0pt]{-}
  & Junior         & 1 700 & 2 800 & 3 200\\
\tabucline[0.2pt blue!40 off 2pt]{.}
& Senior         &  & ? &\\
\tabucline[0.2pt blue!40 off 2pt]{-}
& Specjalist     &  & ? &\\
\tabucline[0.2pt blue!40 off 2pt]{-}
& Team Leader    &  & ? &\\
\tabucline[1pt blue!40 off 0pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
\caption{1. Wynagrodzenia: Procesy HR}
\label{tabela1}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `etoolbox` package one can use

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qhv}\sffamily}{}{}
```

To change to `tgheros` font inside all tables, and there is no need to load the `tgheros` package.

[image]

Comment: @DanielMiliński you are welcome.

Comment: What is the shortcut of TeX Gyre Heros Condensed? And how I can cheek this?

Comment: @DanielMiliński the shortcut is `phvc`. You can look at style file where you can see `\DeclareVoidOption{condensed}{\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qhvc}}`